# In Functional Programming, what is a functor?

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml, functor

I've come across the term 'Functor' a few times while reading various articles on functional programming, but the authors typically assume the reader already understands the term. Looking around on the web has provided either excessively technical descriptions (see the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functor)) or incredibly vague descriptions (see the section on Functors at this [ocaml-tutorial website](http://mirror.pkill.info/ocaml-tutorial.org/modules.html)).

Can someone kindly define the term, explain its use, and perhaps provide an example of how Functors are created and used?

**Edit**: While I am interested in the theory behind the term, I am less interested in the theory than I am in the implementation and practical use of the concept.

**Edit 2**: Looks like there is some cross-terminoligy going on: I'm specifically referring to the Functors of functional programming, not the function objects of C++.

Comment: See also: http://adit.io/posts/2013-04-17-functors,_applicatives,_and_monads_in_pictures.html

Comment: Pretty good answer too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45149475/1498178

Comment: If you are more interested in the practical implementation and usage than on the stratospheric terminology and theory behind the concept, you just need a one liner: a functor exposes a "map" function.

Comment: @RichardGomes IMHO I think it reduces the role of a functor to a simple Java-like interface, which it is not. A functor transforms stuff, it builds new types from existing ones (in Haskell) which means that the types are mapped too. `fmap` maps the functions. There is two kind of mappings involved. That way of seeing things will help to understand category theory (which is more general). I mean it's interesting to understand basic category theory to help us with all the category theory stuff in Haskell (functor, monads, ...).

Comment: @VladtheImpala The blog post is fantastic but, even if it helps a lot, I like to keep in mind that a functor builds (maps to) another type. I particularly like the sentence "A functor F takes each type T and maps it to a new type FT" in [Monads are like burritos](https://blog.plover.com/prog/burritos.html). IMHO it is not just a context (a box) around a value even if that proves practical to see things like this (Haskell PoV vs category theory PoV ?)

Answer (score 289, accepted):

The word "functor" comes from category theory, which is a very general, very abstract branch of mathematics.  It has been borrowed by designers of functional languages in at least two different ways.

- In the ML family of languages, a functor is a module that takes one or more other modules as a parameter.  It's considered an advanced feature, and most beginning programmers have difficulty with it.

  As an example of implementation and practical use, you could define your favorite form of balanced binary search tree once and for all as a functor, and it would take as a parameter a module that provides:

  - The type of key to be used in the binary tree
  - A total-ordering function on keys

  Once you've done this, you can use the same balanced binary tree implementation forever.  (The type of value stored in the tree is usually left polymorphic—the tree doesn't need to look at values other than to copy them around, whereas the tree definitely needs to be able to compare keys, and it gets the comparison function from the functor's parameter.)

  Another application of ML functors is [layered network protocols](http://www-2.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/fox/papers/lfp-signatures.ps).  The link is to a really terrific paper by the CMU Fox group; it shows how to use functors to build more complex protocol layers (like TCP) on type of simpler layers (like IP or even directly over Ethernet).  Each layer is implemented as a functor that takes as a parameter the layer below it.  The structure of the software actually reflects the way people think about the problem, as opposed to the layers existing only in the mind of the programmer.  In 1994 when this work was published, it was a big deal.

  For a wild example of ML functors in action, you could see the paper [ML Module Mania](http://www.cs.tufts.edu/~nr/pubs/maniaws-abstract.html), which contains a publishable (i.e., scary) example of functors at work.  For a brilliant, clear, pellucid explanation of the ML modules system (with comparisons to other kinds of modules), read the first few pages of Xavier Leroy's brilliant 1994 POPL paper [Manifest Types, Modules, and Separate Compilation](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.14.3950).
- In Haskell, and in some related pure functional language, `Functor` is a *type class*.  A type belongs to a type class (or more technically, the type "is an instance of" the type class) when the type provides certain operations with certain expected behavior.  A type `T` can belong to class `Functor` if it has certain collection-like behavior:

  - The type `T` is parameterized over another type, which you should think of as the element type of the collection.  The type of the full collection is then something like `T Int`, `T String`, `T Bool`, if you are containing integers, strings, or Booleans respectively.  If the element type is unknown, it is written as a *type parameter* `a`, as in `T a`.

    Examples include lists (zero or more elements of type `a`), the `Maybe` type (zero or one elements of type `a`), sets of elements of type `a`, arrays of elements of type `a`, all kinds of search trees containing values of type `a`, and lots of others you can think of.
  - The other property that `T` has to satisfy is that if you have a function of type `a -> b` (a function on elements), then you have to be able to take that function and product a related function on collections.  You do this with the operator `fmap`, which is shared by every type in the `Functor` type class.   The operator is actually overloaded, so if you have a function `even` with type `Int -> Bool`, then

    ```
    fmap even
    ```

    is an overloaded function that can do many wonderful things:

    - Convert a list of integers to a list of Booleans
    - Convert a tree of integers to a tree of Booleans
    - Convert `Nothing` to `Nothing` and `Just 7` to `Just False`

    In Haskell, this property is expressed by giving the type of `fmap`:

    ```
    fmap :: (Functor t) => (a -> b) -> t a -> t b
    ```

    where we now have a small `t`, which means "any type in the `Functor` class."

  To make a long story short, in Haskell **a functor is a kind of collection for which if you are given a function on elements, `fmap` will give you back a function on collections**.  As you can imagine, this is an idea that can be widely reused, which is why it is blessed as part of Haskell's standard library.

As usual, people continue to invent new, useful abstractions, and you may want to look into *applicative* functors, for which the best reference may be a paper called [Applicative Programming with Effects](http://strictlypositive.org/IdiomLite.pdf) by Conor McBride and Ross Paterson.

Comment: I understand both ML-functors and Haskell-functors, but lack the insight to relate them together. What's the relationship between these two, in a category-theoretical sense?

Comment: @Wei Hu: Category theory has never made any sense to me.  The best I can say is that all three notions involve mapping.

Comment: According to this Haskell wiki: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Category_theory , it's like this:

A category is a collection of objects and morphisms (functions), where the morphisms are from objects in a category to other objects in that category. A functor is a function which maps objects and morphisms from one category to objects and morphisms in another. Least that's how I understand it. What that means exactly for programming I have yet to understand.

Comment: @WeiHu Pretty late to the game and I really don't know ML at all, but here's an answer which might elucidate the matter a bit: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23236777/1455582

Comment: @norman-ramsey, have you looked at Conceptual Mathematics by Lawvere and Schanuel? I am a total novice to the area but the book is eminently readable and - dare-I-say - enjoyable. (Loved your explanation.)

Comment: Your balanced binary search tree is the only practical example of a functor I have encountered thus far that actually completely makes sense to me.  :)  I wonder if there is a similarly excellent description of "monads" on this site that someone might link to from here...?

Comment: `then you have to be able to take that function and product a related function on collections` Did you mean `produce` instead of `product`?

Comment: Re: category theory, you can think of the collection of types in a langauge as being the objects in a category, with functions being the arrows connecting objects. A functor in category theory maps types to other types, and functions between two types to functions between two mapped types. So in Haskell, for example, `[]` + `fmap` is a functor: `[]` maps types like `Int` to `[Int]`, while `fmap` maps functions like `Char -> Int` to `[Char] -> [Int]`. The tricky part (for me) was that the mapped types don't really have names independent of the functor that maps to them.

Answer (score 71):

Other answers here are complete, but I'll try another explanation of the FP use of *functor*. Take this as analogy:

> A functor is a container of type *a* that, when subjected to a function that maps from *a*→*b*, yields a container of type *b*.

Unlike the abstracted-function-pointer use in C++, here the functor is *not* the function; rather, it's something that behaves consistently when *subjected to a function*.

Comment: _A container of type b_ means "the same kind of container as the input container, but now filled with b's". So if we have a list of bananas, and we _map_ a function that takes a banana and outputs a fruit salad, we now have a list of fruit salads. Likewise, if we had a _tree_ of bananas, and we _map_ the same function, we now would have a _tree_ of apples. Etc. **tree** and **list** are two Functors here.

Comment: "A functor is a container of type a that, when subjected to a function" -- it is actually the other way around -- the function (morphism) is subject to a functor, to be mapped into another morphism

Answer (score 40):

There are three different meanings, not much related!

- In Ocaml it is a parametrized module. See [manual](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/manual004.html). I think the best way to grok them is by example: (written quickly, might be buggy)

  ```
  module type Order = sig
      type t
      val compare: t -> t -> bool
  end;;


  module Integers = struct
      type t = int
      let compare x y = x > y
  end;;

  module ReverseOrder = functor (X: Order) -> struct
      type t = X.t
      let compare x y = X.compare y x
  end;;

  (* We can order reversely *)
  module K = ReverseOrder (Integers);;
  Integers.compare 3 4;;   (* this is false *)
  K.compare 3 4;;          (* this is true *)

  module LexicographicOrder = functor (X: Order) -> 
    functor (Y: Order) -> struct
      type t = X.t * Y.t
      let compare (a,b) (c,d) = if X.compare a c then true
                           else if X.compare c a then false
                           else Y.compare b d
  end;;

  (* compare lexicographically *)
  module X = LexicographicOrder (Integers) (Integers);;
  X.compare (2,3) (4,5);;

  module LinearSearch = functor (X: Order) -> struct
      type t = X.t array
      let find x k = 0 (* some boring code *)
  end;;

  module BinarySearch = functor (X: Order) -> struct
      type t = X.t array
      let find x k = 0 (* some boring code *)
  end;;

  (* linear search over arrays of integers *)
  module LS = LinearSearch (Integers);;
  LS.find [|1;2;3] 2;;
  (* binary search over arrays of pairs of integers, 
     sorted lexicographically *)
  module BS = BinarySearch (LexicographicOrder (Integers) (Integers));;
  BS.find [|(2,3);(4,5)|] (2,3);;
  ```

You can now add quickly many possible orders, ways to form new orders, do a binary or linear search easily over them. Generic programming FTW.

- In functional programming languages like Haskell, it means some type constructors (parametrized types like lists, sets) that can be "mapped". To be precise, a functor `f` is equipped with `(a -> b) -> (f a -> f b)`. This has origins in category theory. The Wikipedia article you linked to is this usage.

  ```
  class Functor f where
      fmap :: (a -> b) -> (f a -> f b)

  instance Functor [] where      -- lists are a functor
      fmap = map

  instance Functor Maybe where   -- Maybe is option in Haskell
      fmap f (Just x) = Just (f x)
      fmap f Nothing = Nothing

  fmap (+1) [2,3,4]   -- this is [3,4,5]
  fmap (+1) (Just 5)  -- this is Just 6
  fmap (+1) Nothing   -- this is Nothing
  ```

So, this is a special kind of a type constructors, and has little to do with functors in Ocaml!

- In imperative languages, it is a pointer to function.

Comment: I have always read that functors are containers - but this is just a poor simplification. Your answer finally provided the missing link: Functors are a type class (type constraint) for parameterized types (type constructors). It's  that simple!

Answer (score 16):

In OCaml, it's a parameterised module.

If you know C++, think of an OCaml functor as a template. C++ only has class templates, and functors work at the module scale.

An example of functor is Map.Make; `module StringMap = Map.Make (String);;` builds a map module that works with String-keyed maps.

You couldn't achieve something like StringMap with just polymorphism; you need to make some assumptions on the keys. The String module contains the operations (comparison, etc) on a totally ordered string type, and the functor will link against the operations the String module contains. You could do something similar with object-oriented programming, but you'd have method indirection overhead.

Comment: I got that from the ocaml website - but I don't understand what the use of a parameterized module would be.

Comment: @Kornel Yeah, what I described is an OCaml concept. The other concept is just “functional value”, which is nothing particular in FP.
@Erik I expanded slightly, but the reference docs are slow to load.

Answer (score 16):

You got quite a few good answers.  I'll pitch in:

A functor, in the mathematical sense, is a special kind of function on an algebra.  It is a minimal function which maps an algebra to another algebra.  "Minimality" is expressed by the functor laws.

There are two ways to look at this.  For example, lists are functors over some type.  That is, given an algebra over a type 'a', you can generate a compatible algebra of lists containing things of type 'a'.  (For example: the map that takes an element to a singleton list containing it:  f(a) = [a]) Again, the notion of compatibility is expressed by the functor laws.

On the other hand, given a functor f "over" a type a, (that is, f a is the result of applying the functor f to the algebra of type a), and function from g: a -> b, we can compute a new functor F = (fmap g) which maps f a to f b.  In short, fmap is the part of F that maps "functor parts" to "functor parts", and g is the part of the function that maps "algebra parts" to "algebra parts".  It takes a function, a functor, and once complete, it IS a functor too.

It might seem that different languages are using different notions of functors, but they're not.  They're merely using functors over different algebras.  OCamls has an algebra of modules, and functors over that algebra let you attach new declarations to a module in a "compatible" way.

A Haskell functor is NOT a type class.  It is a data type with a free variable which satisfies the type class.  If you're willing to dig into the guts of a datatype (with no free variables), you can reinterpret a data type as a functor over an underlying algebra.  For example:

data F = F Int

is isomorphic to the class of Ints.  So F, as a value constructor, is a function that maps Int to F Int, an equivalent algebra.  It is a functor. On the other hand, you don't get fmap for free here.  That's what pattern matching is for.

Functors are good for "attaching" things to elements of algebras, in an algebraically compatible way.

Answer (score 9):

The best answer to that question is found in "Typeclassopedia" by Brent Yorgey.

This issue of Monad Reader contain a precise definition of what a functor is as well as many definition of other concepts as well as a diagram. (Monoid, Applicative, Monad and other concept are explained and seen in relation to a functor).

http://haskell.org/sitewiki/images/8/85/TMR-Issue13.pdf

excerpt from Typeclassopedia for Functor:
"A simple intuition is that a Functor represents a “container” of some 
sort, along with the ability to apply a function uniformly to every element in the 
container"

But really the whole typeclassopedia is a highly recommended reading that is surprisingly easy. In a way you can see the typeclass presented there as a parallel to design pattern in object in the sense that they give you a vocabulary for given behavior or capability.

Cheers

Answer (score 7):

There is a pretty good example in the O'Reilly OCaml book that's on Inria's website (which as of writing this is unfortunately down).  I found a very similar example in this book used by caltech: [Introduction to OCaml (pdf link)](http://www.cs.caltech.edu/courses/cs134/cs134b/book.pdf).  The relevant section is the chapter on functors (Page 139 in the book, page 149 in the PDF).

In the book they have a functor called MakeSet which creates a data structure that consists of a list, and functions to add an element, determine if an element is in the list, and to find the element.  The comparison function that is used to determine if it's in/not in the set has been parametrized (which is what makes MakeSet a functor instead of a module).

They also have a module that implements the comparison function so that it does a case insensitive string compare.

Using the functor and the module that implements the comparison they can create a new module in one line:

```
module SSet = MakeSet(StringCaseEqual);;
```

that creates a module for a set data structure that uses case insensitive comparisons.  If you wanted to create a set that used case sensitive comparisons then you would just need to implement a new comparison module instead of a new data structure module.

Tobu compared functors to templates in C++ which I think is quite apt.

Answer (score 6):

Given the other answers and what I'm going to post now, I'd say that it's a rather heavily overloaded word, but anyway...

For a hint regarding the meaning of the word 'functor' in Haskell, ask GHCi:

```
Prelude> :info Functor
class Functor f where
  fmap :: forall a b. (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
  (GHC.Base.<$) :: forall a b. a -> f b -> f a
        -- Defined in GHC.Base
instance Functor Maybe -- Defined in Data.Maybe
instance Functor [] -- Defined in GHC.Base
instance Functor IO -- Defined in GHC.Base
```

So, basically, a functor in Haskell is something that can be mapped over. Another way to say it is that a functor is something which can be regarded as a container which can be asked to use a given function to transform the value it contains; thus, for lists, `fmap` coincides with `map`, for `Maybe`, `fmap f (Just x) = Just (f x)`, `fmap f Nothing = Nothing` etc.

[The Functor typeclass](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses#the-functor-typeclass) subsection and the section on [Functors, Applicative Functors and Monoids](http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids) of [Learn You a Haskell for Great Good](http://learnyouahaskell.com/) give some examples of where this particular concept is useful. (A summary: lots of places! :-))

Note that any monad can be treated as a functor, and in fact, as Craig Stuntz points out, the most often used functors tend to be monads... OTOH, it is convenient at times to make a type an instance of the Functor typeclass without going to the trouble of making it a Monad. (E.g. in the case of `ZipList` from `Control.Applicative`, mentioned on [one of the aforementioned pages](http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids).)

Answer (score 6):

"Functor is mapping of objects and morphisms that preserves composition and identity of a category."

Lets define what is a category ?

> It's a bunch of objects!
>
> Draw a few dots (for now 2 dots, one is 'a' another is 'b') inside a
>   circle and name that circle A(Category) for now.

What does the category holds ?

> Composition between objects and Identity function for every object.

So, we have to map the objects and preserve the composition after applying our Functor.

Lets imagine 'A' is our category which has objects ['a', 'b'] and there exists a morphism a -> b

Now, we have to define a functor which can map these objects and morphisms into another category 'B'.

Lets say the functor is called 'Maybe'

```
data Maybe a = Nothing | Just a
```

So, The category 'B' looks like this.

Please draw another circle but this time with 'Maybe a' and 'Maybe b' instead of 'a' and 'b'.

Everything seems good and all the objects are mapped

'a' became 'Maybe a' and 'b' became 'Maybe b'.

But the problem is we have to map the morphism from 'a' to 'b' as well.

That means morphism a -> b in 'A' should map to morphism 'Maybe a' -> 'Maybe b'

morphism from a -> b is called f, then morphism from 'Maybe a' -> 'Maybe b' is called 'fmap f'

Now lets see what function 'f' was doing in 'A' and see if we can replicate it in 'B'

function definition of 'f' in 'A':

```
f :: a -> b
```

f takes a and returns b

function definition of 'f' in 'B' :

```
f :: Maybe a -> Maybe b
```

f takes Maybe a and return Maybe b

lets see how to use fmap to map the function 'f' from 'A' to function 'fmap f' in 'B'

definition of fmap

```
fmap :: (a -> b) -> (Maybe a -> Maybe b)
fmap f Nothing = Nothing
fmap f (Just x) = Just(f x)
```

So, what are we doing here ?

We are applying the function 'f' to 'x' which is of type 'a'. Special pattern matching of 'Nothing' comes from the definition of `Functor Maybe`.

So, we mapped our objects [a, b] and morphisms [ f ] from category 'A' to category 'B'.

Thats Functor!

[image]

Comment: Interesting answer. I wish to complement it with [Monads are like burritos](https://blog.plover.com/prog/burritos.html) (funny answer to [Abstraction, intuition, and the “monad tutorial fallacy”](https://byorgey.wordpress.com/2009/01/12/abstraction-intuition-and-the-monad-tutorial-fallacy/)) and his sentence "A functor F takes each type T and maps it to a new type FT" aka a type constructor. [Functional Programming and Category Theory - Categories and Functors](https://nikgrozev.com/2016/03/14/functional-programming-and-category-theory-part-1-categories-and-functors/) was useful too.

Answer (score 5):

Here's an [article on functors from a programming POV](http://scienceblogs.com/goodmath/2006/06/more_category_theory_getting_i.php), followed up by more specifically [how they surface in programming languages](http://scienceblogs.com/goodmath/2006/07/monads_and_programming_languag_1.php).

The practical use of a functor is in a monad, and you can find many tutorials on monads if you look for that.

Comment: "The practical use of a functor is in a monad" -- not only. All monads are functors, but there are lots of uses for non-monad functors.

Comment: I'd say that studying monads to use functors is like saving for a Rolls to go buy groceries.

Answer (score 5):

In a comment to the top-voted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2031421/1455582), user [Wei Hu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/111391/wei-hu) asks:

> I understand both ML-functors and Haskell-functors, but lack the
>   insight to relate them together. What's the relationship between these
>   two, in a category-theoretical sense?

**Note**: I don't know ML, so please forgive and correct any related mistakes.

Let's initially assume that we are all familiar with the definitions of 'category' and 'functor'.

A compact answer would be that "Haskell-functors" are (endo-)functors `F : Hask -> Hask` while "ML-functors" are functors `G : ML -> ML'`.

Here, `Hask` is the category formed by Haskell types and functions between them, and similarly `ML` and `ML'` are categories defined by ML structures.

**Note**: There are some [technical issues](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Hask) with making `Hask` a category, but there are ways around them.

From a category theoretic perspective, this means that a `Hask`-functor is a map `F` of Haskell types:

```
data F a = ...
```

along with a map `fmap` of Haskell functions:

```
instance Functor F where
    fmap f = ...
```

ML is pretty much the same, though there is no canonical `fmap` abstraction I am aware of, so let's define one:

```
signature FUNCTOR = sig
  type 'a f
  val fmap: 'a -> 'b -> 'a f -> 'b f
end
```

That is `f` maps `ML`-types and `fmap` maps `ML`-functions, so

```
functor StructB (StructA : SigA) :> FUNCTOR =
struct
  fmap g = ...
  ...
end
```

is a functor `F: StructA -> StructB`.

Answer (score 5):

### Rough Overview

In functional programming, a *functor* is essentially a construction of lifting ordinary **unary** functions (i.e. those with one argument) to functions between variables of new types. It is much easier to write and maintain simple functions between plain objects and use functors to lift them, then to manually write functions between complicated container objects. Further advantage is to write plain functions only once and then re-use them via different functors.

Examples of functors include arrays, "maybe" and "either" functors, futures (see e.g. https://github.com/Avaq/Fluture), and many others.

### Illustration

Consider the function constructing the full person's name from the first and last names. We could define it like `fullName(firstName, lastName)` as function of two arguments, which however would not be suitable for functors that only deal with functions of one arguments. To remedy, we collect all the arguments in a single object `name`, which now becomes the function's single argument:

```
// In JavaScript notation
fullName = name => name.firstName + ' ' + name.lastName
```

Now what if we have many people in an array? Instead of manually go over the list, we can simply re-use our function `fullName` via the `map` method provided for arrays with short single line of code:

```
fullNameList = nameList => nameList.map(fullName)
```

and use it like

```
nameList = [
    {firstName: 'Steve', lastName: 'Jobs'},
    {firstName: 'Bill', lastName: 'Gates'}
]

fullNames = fullNameList(nameList) 
// => ['Steve Jobs', 'Bill Gates']
```

That will work, whenever every entry in our `nameList` is an object providing both `firstName` and `lastName` properties. But what if some objects don't (or even aren't objects at all)? To avoid the errors and make the code safer, we can wrap our objects into the `Maybe` type (se e.g. https://sanctuary.js.org/#maybe-type):

```
// function to test name for validity
isValidName = name => 
    (typeof name === 'object') 
    && (typeof name.firstName === 'string')
    && (typeof name.lastName === 'string')

// wrap into the Maybe type
maybeName = name => 
    isValidName(name) ? Just(name) : Nothing()
```

where `Just(name)` is a container carrying only valid names and `Nothing()` is the special value used for everything else. Now instead of interrupting (or forgetting) to check the validity of our arguments, we can simply reuse (lift) our original `fullName` function with another single line of code, based again on the `map` method, this time provided for the Maybe type:

```
// Maybe Object -> Maybe String
maybeFullName = maybeName => maybeName.map(fullName)
```

and use it like

```
justSteve = maybeName(
    {firstName: 'Steve', lastName: 'Jobs'}
) // => Just({firstName: 'Steve', lastName: 'Jobs'})

notSteve = maybeName(
    {lastName: 'SomeJobs'}
) // => Nothing()

steveFN = maybeFullName(justSteve)
// => Just('Steve Jobs')

notSteveFN = maybeFullName(notSteve)
// => Nothing()
```

### Category Theory

A **Functor** in *Category Theory* is a map between two categories respecting composition of their morphisms. In a *Computer Language*, the main Category of interest is the one whose **objects** are *types* (certain sets of values), and whose **morphisms** are functions `f:a->b` from one type `a` to another type `b`.

For example, take `a` to be the `String` type, `b` the Number type, and `f` is the function mapping a string into its length:

```
// f :: String -> Number
f = str => str.length
```

Here `a = String` represents the set of all strings and `b = Number` the set of all numbers. In that sense, both `a` and `b` represent objects in the *Set Category* (which is closely related to the category of types, with the difference being inessential here). In the Set Category, **morphisms** between two sets are precisely all functions from the first set into the second. So our length function `f` here is a morphism from the set of strings into the set of numbers.

As we only consider the set category, the relevant *Functors* from it into itself are maps sending objects to objects and morphisms to morphisms, that satisfy certain algebraic laws.

### Example: `Array`

`Array` can mean many things, but only one thing is a Functor -- the type construct, mapping a type `a` into the type `[a]` of all arrays of type `a`. For instance, the `Array` functor maps the type `String`  into the type `[String]` (the set of all arrays of strings of arbitrary length), and set type `Number` into the corresponding type `[Number]` (the set of all arrays of numbers).

It is important not to confuse the Functor map

```
Array :: a => [a]
```

with a morphism `a -> [a]`. The functor simply maps (associates) the type `a` into the type `[a]` as one thing to another. That each type is actually a set of elements, is of no relevance here. In contrast, a morphism is an actual function between those sets. For instance, there is a natural morphism (function)

```
pure :: a -> [a]
pure = x => [x]
```

which sends a value into the 1-element array with that value as single entry. That function is **not** a part of the `Array` Functor! From the point of view of this functor, `pure` is just a function like any other, nothing special.

On the other hand, the `Array` Functor has its second part -- the morphism part. Which maps a morphism `f :: a -> b` into a morphism `[f] :: [a] -> [b]`:

```
// a -> [a]
Array.map(f) = arr => arr.map(f)
```

Here `arr` is any array of arbitrary length with values of type `a`, and `arr.map(f)` is the array of the same length with values of type `b`, whose entries are results of applying `f` to the entries of `arr`. To make it a functor, the mathematical laws of mapping identity to identity and compositions to compositions must hold, which are easy to check in this `Array` example.

Answer (score 2):

Not to contradict the previous theoretical or mathematical answers, but a Functor is also an Object (in an Object-Oriented programming language) that has only one method and is effectively used as a function.

An example is the Runnable interface in Java, which has only one method: run.

Consider this example, first in Javascript, which has first-class functions:

```
[1, 2, 5, 10].map(function(x) { return x*x; });
```

Output:
[1, 4, 25, 100]

The map method takes a function and returns a new array with each element being the result of the application of that function to the value at the same position in the original array.

To do the same thing is Java, using a Functor, you would first need to define an interface, say:

```
public interface IntMapFunction {
  public int f(int x);
}
```

Then, if you add a collection class which had a map function, you could do:

```
myCollection.map(new IntMapFunction() { public int f(int x) { return x * x; } });
```

This uses an in-line subclass of IntMapFunction to create a Functor, which is the OO equivalent of the function from the earlier JavaScript example.

Using Functors let you apply functional techniques in an OO language.  Of course, some OO languages also have support for functions directly, so this isn't required.

Reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_object

Comment: Actually "function object" is not a correct description of a functor. E.g. `Array` is a functor, but `Array(value)` only gives 1-element arrays.

Answer (score 2):

### KISS: A functor is an object that has a map method.

Arrays in JavaScript implement map and are therefore functors. Promises, Streams and Trees often implement map in functional languages, and when they do, they are considered functors. The map method of the functor takes it’s own contents and transforms each of them using the transformation callback passed to map, and returns a new functor, which contains the structure as the first functor, but with the transformed values.

src: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DisD9ftUyCk&feature=youtu.be&t=76

Comment: With the side note that 'object' should be taken very broadly and just means 'something'. For OOP-languages, for instance, substitute *object* for *class*. One could say 'a functor is a class that implements the Functor interface' (Of course, this interface might not be physically there, but you could lift the 'map' logic out to that interface, and have all of your mappable classes share it -- as long as your type system allows typing things this general, that is).

Comment: I find Classes super confusing to be honest, on one side they are just a blueprint for something concrete / but they may also have methods (static stuff) and can behave like objects.
Does the Class implement the interface or the instance it creates?

Comment: Yes, they can be confusing. But: Classes _implement_ interfaces (they 'fill in' the blanks that were given in the interfaces methods. In other words: They turn the abstract guidelines of the interface in a concrete guideline that can be instantly (forgive the pun) instantiated). As to 'classes behave like objects': In truly OOP-languages like Ruby, Classes are instances of the 'Class' Class. It's turtles all the way down.

Comment: `Array` type construct defines a single functor. Its instances are also called "arrays" but they are not functors. The description here should be made more precise.

Comment: @DmitriZaitsev Could you elaborate? So what you are saying is that instances are not functors? I dont see the sence in that since you get a new functor by mapping over one.

Comment: @soundyogi To have a simpler example, a number is an instance of both addition and multiplication group. So you cannot define the inverse of a number, unless you specify the operation. Similarly, to map an instance over a function, you need to know the complete functor, not just the instance.

Comment: Also your definition is incorrect because you don't mention the functor laws.

Comment: Yes it is not the most complete answer, but I found its simplicity intruiging. I will have to read about what you mentioned. I think I see what you mean. Thanks.

Comment: @soundyogi 'Not the most complete' is not the same as incorrect :). Simplicity is only good when it helps, not obscures.

Answer (score 0):

In functional programming, error handling is different. Throwing and catching exceptions is imperative code. Instead of using `try/catch` block, a safety box is created around the code that might throw an error. this is a fundamental design pattern in functional programming. A wrapper object is used to encapsulate a potentially erroneous value. The wrapper's main purpose is to provide a 'different' way to use the wrapped object

```
 const wrap = (val) => new Wrapper(val);
```

Wrapping guards direct access to the values so they can be manipulated
safely and immutably. Because we won’t have direct access to it, the only way to extract it is to use the `identity function`.

```
identity :: (a) -> a
```

This is another use case of identity function: Extracting data functionally from encapsulated types.

[image]

The Wrapper type uses the map to safely access and manipulate values. In this case,  we are mapping the identity function over the container to extract the value from the container. With this approach, we can check for null before calling the function, or check for an empty string, a negative number, and so on.

```
 fmap :: (A -> B) -> Wrapper[A] -> Wrapper[B]
```

fmap, first opens the container, then applies the given function to its value, and finally closes the value back into a new container of the same type. This type of function is called a `functor`.

- fmap returns a new copy of the container at each invocation.
- functors are side-effect-free
- functors must be composable

Answer (score 0):

A ***functor*** is a class object which behaves like a function.

```python
inky_the_inkrementor = Inkrementor(1)
# running total is 1

inky_the_inkrementor(10)
# running total is 11

inky_the_inkrementor(100) 
# running total is 111

inky_the_inkrementor(1000)
# running total is 1111

inky_the_inkrementor(10000) 
# running total is 11111

inky_the_inkrementor(100000)
# running total is 111111

inky_the_inkrementor(9)(1)(10)(100)
# running total is 111111

inky_the_inkrementor(500000, 50000, 5000)
# the running total is 1555111

print(int(inky_the_inkrementor))
# prints 1555111
```

After you instantiate a ***functor*** and you can write `()` on the right-hand side.

Below, we have an examples of a functor written in *python*

---

## Python

```cpp
class Inkrementor:

    def __init__(this, *args):
        this._num = 0
        this(*args)

    def __call__(this, *args):
        left      = float(args[0])

        leftovers = this(*args[1:])

        this._num += left + leftovers

        return this 

    def __float__(this):
        return this._num
```

Answer (score -4):

In practice, functor means an object that implements the call operator in C++. In ocaml I think functor refers to something that takes a module as input and output another module.

Answer (score -5):

Put simply, a functor, or function object, is a class object that can be called just like a function.

In C++:

This is how you write a function

```cpp
void foo() 
{
    cout << "Hello, world! I'm a function!";
}
```

This is how you write a functor

```cpp
class FunctorClass
{
    public:
    void operator ()
    {
        cout << "Hello, world! I'm a functor!";
    }
};
```

Now you can do this:

```
foo(); //result: Hello, World! I'm a function!

FunctorClass bar;
bar(); //result: Hello, World! I'm a functor!
```

What makes these so great is that you can keep state in the class - imagine if you wanted to ask a function how many times it has been called. There's no way to do this in a neat, encapsulated way. With a function object, it's just like any other class: you'd have some instance variable that you increment in `operator ()` and some method to inspect that variable, and everything's neat as you please.

Comment: No, those functors aren't the type theory notion that is used by FP languages.

Comment: I can kind of see how one could prove that `FunctorClass` fulfils the first Functor Law, but could you sketch out a proof for the second Law? I don't quite see it.

Comment: Bah, you guys are right. I took a stab at solving the "web has provided exceedingly technical descriptions" and overshot, trying to avoid, "In the ML family of languages, a functor is a module that takes one or more other modules as a parameter." This answer, however, is, well, bad. Oversimplified and underspecified. I'm tempted to ragedelete it, but I'll leave it for future generations to shake their heads at :)

Comment: I'm glad you left the answer and comments, because it helps frame the problem. Thank you! I'm having trouble in that most of the answers are written in terms of Haskell or OCaml, and to me that's a little like explaining alligators in terms of crocodiles.

Comment: @Tobu The question was "what is a ***functor***?" The question was not "what is a ***functor*** in type theory notation?" This answer is of very good quality.

Answer (score -10):

Functor is not specifically related to functional programming. It's just a "pointer" to a function or some kind of object, that can be called as it would be a function.

Comment: There is a specific FP concept of a functor (from category theory), but you're right that the same word is also used for other things in non-FP languages.

Comment: Are you sure that function pointers are Functors? I don't see how function pointers fulfil the two Functor Laws, especially the Second Functor Law (preservation of morphism composition). Do you have a proof for that? (Just a rough sketch.)

Comment: Usually people call those "function pointers", but if you want to call it a "function" that is fine by me. You could choose to define a  ***functor*** to be anything other than a function which has the same interface as a function.