# How to compare string in OCaml?

Tags: string, ocaml, string-comparison

How to compare strings in OCaml? If i have a string a = "abcd" and string z = "Z" z > a is false. String compare z a is negative. I want it to recognize "Z" as bigger than "abcd", is there a specific function for this?

Comment: Is it possible for you to use `String.uppercase_ascii`? (works since OCaml v. 4.03.0). `String.uppercase_ascii a < z` returns `true`. The problem is in the fact that in ASCII 'a' > 'Z'.

Comment: You should provide some more context preferably in the form of OCaml code.

Comment: I searched for "case insensitive string comparison ocaml" and found a [reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030863/in-functional-programming-what-is-a-functor/2031086?s=1|0.2538#2031086) to a possible way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3):

The generic comparison function provided by Ocaml is guaranteed to work for any type and to be a total order but that's all. In particular there is no guarantee that it corresponds to a meaningful order.
So if you don't like it just use something else, for instance using `<` instead of `>` will give you the result you want for "abcd" and "Z".