# Haskell function composition and fmap f

Tags: haskell

I have two simple examples:

1) `xt` function (what is this?)

```
Prelude> :t fmap
fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
Prelude> :{
Prelude| f::Int->Int
Prelude| f x = x
Prelude| :}
Prelude> xt = fmap f // ?
Prelude> :t xt
xt :: Functor f => f Int -> f Int
Prelude> xt (+2) 1
3
```

2) `xq` function (via composition)

```
Prelude> :{
Prelude| return x = [x]
Prelude| :}
Prelude> xq = return . f
Prelude> :t xq
xq :: Int -> [Int]
Prelude> :t return
return :: a -> [a]
```

`xq` function I get through composition `return(f(x))`. But what does that mean: `fmap f` and what is difference?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Functional Programming, what is a functor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030863/in-functional-programming-what-is-a-functor)

Comment: @chepner My question was not, what a `functor` is. I would like to know what does the notation `fmap  f` mean

Comment: If you knew what a functor was, it would be obvious what `fmap f` means. It's not special syntax, it's just function application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Functor` instance for `(->) r` defines `fmap` to be function composition:

```
fmap f g = f . g
```

Thus, `xt (+2) == fmap f (+2) == f . (+2) == (+2)` (since `f` is the identity function for `Int`). Applied to 1, you get the observed answer 3.

---

`fmap` is the function defined by the `Functor` type class:

```
class Functor f where
    fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

It takes a function as its argument and returns a new function "lifted" into the functor in question. The exact definition is supplied by the `Functor` instance. Above is the definition for the function functor; here for reference are some simpler ones for lists and `Maybe`:

```
instance Functor [] where
    fmap = map

instance Functor Maybe where
    fmap f Nothing = Nothing
    fmap f (Just x) = Just (f x)

> fmap (+1) [1,2,3]
[2,3,4]
> fmap (+1) Nothing
Nothing
> fmap (+1) (Just 3)
Just 4
```

Since you can think of functors as boxes containing one or more values, the intuition for the function functor is that a function is a box containing the result of applying the function to its argument. That is, `(+2)` is a box that contains some value plus 2. (F)mapping a function on that box provides a box that contains the result of applying `f` to the result of the original function, i.e, produces a function that is the composition of `f` with the original function.

Comment: Thanks, but what does the following syntax mean `fmap f`? That is not a product of two functions. Is it?

Comment: `fmap f` is `fmap` applied to `f`, which results in a function. Just like `negate 3` is `negate` applied to `3`, which results in a number

Comment: "`fmap`  takes a function as its argument and returns a new function "lifted" into the functor in question". 
`xt = fmap f` therefore `xt :: Functor f => f Int -> f Int`, but why can not I write `fmap . f`, what is problem here? `return . f` composition works and I get no error. `fmap. fmap` too...

Comment: `fmap` *takes* a function as an argument; it is not applied to the return value of the function. Consider `map` (which is `fmap` for lists): `map (+1) [1,2,3]` does not apply `(+1)` to the list, then pass the result to `map`; instead, `map` takes (+1)` as an argument and returns  a *new* function which takes a list as its input.

Comment: @garychaudhry `\f -> fmap . f :: Functor f => (c -> a -> b) -> c -> f a -> f b`, so for `fmap . f` to make sense, `f` should have type `f :: c -> a -> b`. For example, `fmap . (*)` works - because `(fmap . (*)) 3 = fmap ((*) 3) = fmap (3*)`. We can find types of expressions at GHCi prompt with `:t` command, like `Prelude> :t fmap . (*)`.

Answer (score 1):

Both `xq = return . f`  and `xt = fmap f` can be *eta-expanded*:

```
xq x = (return . f) x = return (f x) = return x
```

Now it can be *eta-contracted*:

```
xq = return
```

The second is

```
xt y = fmap f y = fmap (\x -> x) y = fmap id y = id y = y
```

`fmap` has type `:: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b` so `fmap f` has type `:: Functor f => f Int -> f Int`, because `f :: Int -> Int`. From its type we see that `fmap f` is a function, expecting an `Int`, and producing an `Int`.

Since `f x = x` for `Int`s by definition, it means that `f = id` for `Int`s, where `id` is a predefined function defined just the same way as `f` is (but in general, for any type).

Then  by **Functor laws** *(and that's *all* we need to know about *"Functors"* here)*, `fmap id = id` and so `xt y = y`, in other words it's also `id` - but only for `Int`s,

```
xt = id :: Int -> Int
```

Naturally, `xt (+2) = id (+2) = (+2)`.

---

*Addendum:* for something to be a "Functor" means that it can be substituted for `f` in

```
fmap id (x :: f a) = x
(fmap g . fmap h)  = fmap (g . h)
```

so that the expressions involved make sense (i.e. are well formed, i.e. have a type), and the above equations hold (they are in fact the two "Functor laws").