# When and why to Lift a Function

Tags: scala, functional-programming, lifting, option-type

Consider this code:

```
def f1(a: Int, b: Int) = a + b

def f2(a: Option[Int], b: Option[Int]): Int = (a, b) match {
  case (Some(x), Some(y)) => x + y
  case _ => throw new IllegalArgumentException
}

println(f1(10, 20))
println(f2(Some(10), Some(20)))
```

I heard you can "lift" f1 to be like f2. As a beginner I have the following question:

What is lifting and why it used? In terms of implementation, how can I "lift" f1?

Any explanation is greatly appreciated as it is a bit tricky to find why I would "lift" something

Comment: Note that `f2` isn't really a good function. If it can only operates with **Somes** it shouldn't have asked for **Options**. It would be better if it would return another **Option** instead of throwing an exception.

Comment: Thanks @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez, I tried to write a demo function just for this que, but for my real work I will keep what you said in mind

Comment: You would lift something to reuse your pure function inside different contexts. You lift a single argument function with a functor and an n-ary function with a composition of applicative functors. You don't need monads for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why: when you have a function with signature like `f1` and want to "call it" on `Option[Int]`s (or `List[Int]`s, etc)

How: you could write it directly:

```
def lift2option[A, B, C](f: (A, B) => C): (Option[A], Option[B]) => Option[C] = ???
```

I'm leaving it undefined because you should try writing it yourself; your definition of `f2` should be a good starting point. Note that I made it return `Option[Int]` instead of `Int`. Later I can edit and give the answer if you want.

And then instead of defining `f2` as separate function, you do:

```
val f2 = lift2option(f1 _)
println(f2(Some(10), Some(20)))
```

Of course, the point is that now for *any* function with a signature like `f1` you can get an `f2` equivalent.

It can be further generalized to work not only for `Option`, but you'll want to look into that later.

Comment: Thanks @Alexey, that makes a lot more sense to me now. I kept seeing defintions of Functors and Monads (which I aint learnt yet) but wanted a more basic explanation

Comment: Yes, those are what you need to generalize as mentioned in the last sentence :) To be more precise, functors let you lift functions of 1 argument, and applicative functors (which are between functors and monads) lift functions of 2 or more arguments.

Answer (score 2):

I just wanted to add that lifting a function can be used as an alternative to mapping over a [functor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030863/in-functional-programming-what-is-a-functor). For example, if you had 2 `Option[Int]` objects which you wanted to apply `f1` to, you could do this:

```
val sum: Option[Int] = option1.flatMap { x => option2.map{ y => x + y } }
```

*Note that the result is an `Option[Int]`. As Alexey Romanov said, the return type of `f2` should also be an `Option`. The whole point of `Option` is to let you do operations on a value without fear of `NullPointerException`s or other errors because the value doesn't exist.*

However, this mapping is a bit verbose, and it's annoying having to decide when you need to use `flatMap` and `map`. This is where lifting comes in handy.

Let's define `f2` a little better to handle `None`s:

```
def f2(a: Option[Int], b: Option[Int]): Option[Int] =
  a match {
    case Some(x) => b match {
      case Some(y) => Some(x + y)
      case None => None
    }
    case None => None
  }
```

We can also define this in terms of `f1` by replacing `x + y` with `f1(x + y)`

```
def f2(a: Option[Int], b: Option[Int]): Option[Int] =
  a match {
    case Some(x) => b match {
      case Some(y) => Some(f1(x, y))
      case None => None
    }
    case None => None
  }
```

Right now, `f2` doesn't need to know anything about how to add numbers, it just uses `f1` to add them. We could even make `f1` a parameter of `f2`, in fact.

```
def f2(f1: (Int, Int) => Int)(a: Option[Int], b: Option[Int]): Option[Int] =
  a match {
    case Some(x) => b match {
      case Some(y) => Some(f1(x, y))
      case None => None
    }
    case None => None
  }
```

See what happened there? We just used `f2` to "lift" `f1` from `(Int, Int) => Int` to `(Option[Int], Option[Int]) => Option[Int]`. Let's rename it `lift2`, actually. We could also make it more generic:

```
def lift2[A, B, C](f1: (A, B) => C)(a: Option[A], b: Option[B]): Option[C] =
  a match {
    case Some(x) => b match {
      case Some(y) => Some(f1(x, y))
      case None => None
    }
    case None => None
  }
```

`lift2` is now a function that takes a function of type `(A, B) => C` (here, `A`, `B`, and `C` are all `Int` for `f1`) and returns another function of type `(Option[A], Option[B]) => Option[C]`. Now, we don't have to use those awkward nested `map`s and `flatMap`s. You can just do this:

```
val sum: Option[Int] = lift2(f1)(option1, option2)
```

You can also define `lift3`, `lift4`, etc., of course, but it's probably easier to define just a `lift1` function and use [currying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36314/what-is-currying) to do the rest.

Of course, you can only `lift` a function if you know how to take apart and put together the type that you are lifting to. For example, if `Some` were an object with a private `unapply` method, and it were impossible to pattern match on it, you wouldn't be able to lift `f1`. The same would happen if the constructor for `Some` were private and it were impossible for you to make new `Option`s.

Edit: Here's how you can add multiple `Option[Int]` objects together with `f1` and the `lift2` function.

```
val f2 = lift2(f1)
val optionSum = f2(f2(option1, option2), option3)
```

Without f2, it'd look something like this

```
val sum1 = option1 match {
  case Some(x) => option2 match {
    case Some(y) => Some(f1(x, y))
    case None => None
  }
  case None => None
}
val finalSum = sum1 match {
  case Some(x) => option3 match {
    case Some(y) => Some(f1(x, y))
    case None => None
  }
  case None => None
}
```

Comment: Functor/Applicative embodies the idea of lifting a pure function. What do you lift in your examples? Where is the code reuse, which is usually obtained by lifting?

Comment: @bob I've lifted `f1`. I've put an example at the end for adding 2 Options, but I can put an example for adding multiple Options if you like

Comment: @bob I've updated my answer to include an example of adding 3 `Option[Int]` objects together without lifting `f1`